# How do I select items in an array using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this line which successfully select all elements of class"myclass" on my page:

```
var myTerms = $(".myTerm");
```

The above line works, myTerms is an array of all the myTerm, each of which contain "subTerms".

Then as i iterate over each myTerm, I want to use jQuery to return an array of the "subTerms" within that myTerm.

I tried:

```
var myTerms = $(".myTerm");
for (var i = 0; i < myTerms.length; i++) {
    var myTerm = queryTerms[i];
    subTerms = myTerm.$("subTerms");
```

But that's a no go.
Is jQuery even intended for this or is it better to fall back to plain old java script.

**EDIT**

subTerm is the className of elements inside of myTerm

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the "subTerms" after you fetch em?

Comment: the subTerms are actually exclusively dropdowns so I just want to get their values.

Comment: Could you give a HTML example of some terms for us?  Its hard to do this stuff blind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kinda confused on what the subterms object is, but I'll give it a shot.

```
$('.myTerm').each(function(){
  subTerms = $(this).children();
});
```

** Edit **

If you want the select options, do

```
$('.myTerm').each(function(){
  subTerms = $(this).children('.subTerm option');
});
```

Comment: .children() assumes direct descendants right? perhaps .find() is what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're asking. It sounds like you want to match all items which have the class myterm + another class in your list, e.g. `<li class="myterm subterm1">`

I'd handle this in a selector. jQuery selectors can match on multiple classes if they're comma sparated, e.g. "subterm1, subterm2, subterm3" so if you join them into a string, you can filter on it.

```
var result = $(".myterm").filter(myterms.join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to point out.   `$(".myTerm")` is not an array - its a jquery object, you can use for loops on it, but `each` is much better.  Inside of an `each()` function `this` refers to the `DOMElement`.  Also, if you want to search for more objects INSIDE of a jQuery object you can use `$element.find('.subterm')` or `$('.subTerm', element)`

```
$(".myTerm").each(funciton() {
   // look for any .subTerm that exist underneath of us
   var subTerms = $(".subTerm", this);

   // do something with subTerms as an example....
   var text = [];
   subTerms.each(function() {
     // .val() assuming its an option element
     // .text() might be better.
     text.push($(this).val()); 
   });

   alert(text.join(";"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can scope the second query call to just look under the found term

```
$(".myTerms").each(function() { 
  var sub = $(".subTerms", this);
});
```

Comment: nice condensed version of my answer 3 minutes before yours. ;)

Comment: I'm a slow typer, what can I say :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your code, then you can use the following

```
var myTerms = $(".myTerm");
for (var i = 0; i < myTerms.length; i++) {
    var myTerm = queryTerms[i];
    var $myTerm = $(myTerm);
    subTerms = $myTerm.find("subTerms");
}
```